# Layout Constraints Only Applied In Certain Conditions When Size Class Changes

Tags: ios, autolayout, size-classes

I have a container view controller which contains 2 views. One is a video and the other is chat. In portrait mode, the user can see both the video and the chat; however, in landscape, I want it to only show the video.

**What I've done:**

I use size classes and for `wCompact and hCompact` (iPhone 6 landscape), I remove the chat view and update the constraints. It 'partially' works.

If I start my application in landscape, the video will be shown in full. When I rotate to portrait, I get both the video and chat views. Finally, if I rotate it back to landscape, I only get the video view again. This is the desired behavior. See this GIF:

[image: View and chat view constraints updated]

**The problem:**

If I start the app in portrait, it shows both the video and chat view. Then, when I rotate it to landscape, the chat view is removed but the video view does not update to its new layout constraints. See the GIF below:

[image: Video view constraints not updated]

I suspect this has something to do with the view using a `MPMoviePlayerController` or the fact that it's fetching/streaming data. I don't know.

I'm not even sure what to google to help with this so if anyone has anything, please let me know.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Use `AVPlayerViewController` and `AVPlayer`. It just works. `MPMoviePlayerController` is buggy